# operations in methods don't get saved to my variable

Tags: java

This is my first time using stackoverflow. I don't know if i am doing it right. So anyways, i am trying to make calculator on Java. I am not sure how to explain my problem. operations in methods don't get saved. when i try to add number, it doesn't apply to last state of it. it applies to first number i gave. can you help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gelismishesap
{
    public static void toplam(int k)
    {Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(k + " + ");
        for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
        {
            int b = a.nextInt();
            k += b;
            System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
    public static void cikarma(int k) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(k + " - ");
        for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
        {
            int b = a.nextInt();
            k -= b;
            System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
    public static void carpma(int k) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(k + " x ");
        for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
        {
            int b = a.nextInt();
            k *= b;
            System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
    public static void bolme(int k) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(k + " / ");
        for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
        {
            int b = a.nextInt();
            k /= b;
            System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Sayı girin: ");
        int anasayi = a.nextInt();
        System.out.println(anasayi);
        while(true)
        {
           String b = a.nextLine();
        if(b.equals("q")) { break; }
        if(b.equals("a")) { toplam(anasayi); }
        if(b.equals("b")) { cikarma(anasayi); }
        if(b.equals("c")) { carpma(anasayi); }
        if(b.equals("d")) { bolme(anasayi); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add following to your question input and output to your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java primarily uses call by value whenever argument(s) are passed to method(s) unlike C/C++ where we can prefix argument with '&' to signify that the changes to formal parameters should be reflected to the actual parameters. So you can achieve the desired functionality via passing your result down the stack or you can utilize 'this' pointer.

1. ***Passing the result of an operation to the calling stack***

   Kindly notice I have added a return statement to your mathematical operations functions and accordingly modified the method's signature too.

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class gelismishesap {
      public static int toplam(int k) {
           Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print(k + " + ");
           for(int i =fj 0; i<1; i++)
           {
               int b = a.nextInt();
               k += b;
               System.out.println(k);
           }
           return k;
       }
       public static int cikarma(int k) {
           Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.prfjint(k + " - ");
           for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
           {
               int b = a.nextInt();
               k -= b;
               System.out.println(k);
           }
           return k;
       }
       public static int carpma(int k) {
           Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print(k + " x ");
           for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
           {
               int b = a.nextInt();
               k *= b;
               System.out.println(k);
           }
           return k;
       }
       public static int bolme(int k) {
           Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print(k + " / ");
           for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
           {
               int b = a.nextInt();
               k /= b;
               System.out.println(k);
           }
           return k;
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("Sayı girin: ");
           int anasayi = a.nextInt();
           System.out.println(anasayi);
           while(true)
           {
              String b = a.nextLine();
           if(b.equals("q")) { break; }
           if(b.equals("a")) { anasayi=toplam(anasayi); }
           if(b.equals("b")) { anasayi=cikarma(anasayi); }
           if(b.equals("c")) { anasayi=carpma(anasayi); }
           if(b.equals("d")) { anasayi=bolme(anasayi); }// This will be approx as float holds decimal values
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. ***Updating the number with the help of this pointer***

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class gelismishesap{
   int anasayi; // instance variable
   public void toplam() {

       Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print(this.anasayi + " + ");
       for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
       {
           int b = a.nextInt();
           this.anasayi += b;
           System.out.println(this.anasayi);
       }
   }
   public void cikarma() {
       Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print(this.anasayi + " - ");
       for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
       {
           int b = a.nextInt();
           this.anasayi -= b;
           System.out.println(this.anasayi);
       }
   }
   public void carpma() {
       Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print(this.anasayi + " x ");
       for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
       {
           int b = a.nextInt();
           this.anasayi *= b;
           System.out.println(this.anasayi);
       }
   }
   public void bolme() {
       Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print(this.anasayi + " / ");
       for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
       {
           int b = a.nextInt();
           this.anasayi /= b;
           System.out.println(this.anasayi);
       }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Sayı girin: ");
       gelismishesap ref = new gelismishesap(); // you will need an object(instance) to manipulate instance variables
       ref.anasayi = a.nextInt();
       System.out.println(ref.anasayi);
       while(true)
       {
          String b = a.nextLine();
       if(b.equals("q")) { break; }
       if(b.equals("a")) { ref.toplam(); }
       if(b.equals("b")) { ref.cikarma(); }
       if(b.equals("c")) { ref.carpma(); }
       if(b.equals("d")) { ref.bolme(); }
       }
   }}
   ```

   Note: Please don't use static members too much while coding because they tend to occupy memory throughout the lifetime of application and hence add a lot of cost overhead. Moreover they defy the main objectives of OOP technology/languages. You may use them for constants and labels in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move this section inside the while loop. This way anasayi gets reassigned

```
System.out.print("Sayı girin: ");
int anasayi = a.nextInt();
System.out.println(anasayi);
```

Comment: that won't be a good fix. This will require the end user to enter the resultant number manually to achieve the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive types like int are passed to methods *by value*. It means that your methods get a copy of your k variable. To make your code work, define k as shared variable instead of passing it through methods like this: 
*(although it's very-very bad practice, but you'll learn how to do it right later :) )*

```
public class gelismishesap {

    static int k = 0;

    public static void toplam() {
        // Your code ....
        k += b;
    }

    // Other methods ....

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // Code ....
         k = a.nextInt(); // Instead of anasayi
    }

}
```

And please, write your questions in English later, including names in your code :)

Comment: ohh okay. i got it now. i didnt knew that shared variables exist. thank you